# cashfree payment getway not able to use generated token

Tags: flutter, token, payment-gateway, payment

after generating token and session id, not able to use token.

below mentioned error is occurred.

`E/ConfigRequestHandler(19184): onError : {"message":"token is not present","code":"order_token_invalid","type":"request_failed"}`

i'm trying to use cashfree payment flutter package integration for payment getaway in flutter.

Answer (score 1):

Check environment

CFEnvironment environment = CFEnvironment.SANDBOX;

Check for which environment you have created the orderid and sessionId. It should be same If you have generated token for SANDBOX/TEST app, and you configured it for production from the flutter side.
In that case it won't work

Comment: Check for which environment you have created the orderid and sessionId.
It should be same  

If you have generated token for SANDBOX/TEST app, and you configured it for production from the flutter side.

In that case it won't work

Comment: Please add those details directly in the answer ([edit])